# 【iOS13】why call method`retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:`does not return any peripheral

Tags: core-bluetooth, ios13

I make sure that there has peripheral in system-bluetooth and match services when I call the method retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices,but does not return any peripheral object

Comment: Are you sure some other app has a connection to that peripheral?

Comment: yeah, I am sure.

Comment: these retrievePeripherals code are worked in iOS12

Comment: Submit beta feedback?

Comment: only in this way. The strange thing is that no one else has found this problem.

Answer (score 0):

in iOS 13 you should wait until the CBCentralManager state is in on state before retrieving peripherals.